# SqlAlchemy could not open relation with OID using psycopg2 on Redshift

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I have a python script such as:

```
db = connection.get_engine(my_conn)
run_query(db, query1, LOGGER)
run_query(db, query2, LOGGER)
run_query(db, query3, LOGGER)
run_query(db, query4, LOGGER)
run_query(db, query5, LOGGER)
```

It is returning the following error when running `query4`, but sometimes returns the same in a previous query.

```
(psycopg2.errors.InternalError_) could not open relation with OID 3463635
```

The `get_engine` function is:

```
config = json.load(open(FILE, "r"))
    tangelo_bi_redshift_engine = create_engine(
        "redshift+psycopg2://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}".format(
            config["usr"], config["pwd"], config["host"], config["prt"], config["db"], connect_timeout=60, **kwargs),
        connect_args={'sslmode': 'prefer'})
    return con
```

The `run_query` function is:

```
conn = db.connect()
    try:
        conn.execute(query)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(str(e))
        raise
    finally:
        conn.close()
    return
```

Recently I have been changing code, but nothing related at all to this. But I touched some functions that worked with `Boto3`. As you can see any of them is related to that library.

Furthermore, I tried the query4 in the SQL IDE I use:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table (field)
            SELECT field 
            FROM stg_table stg
            LEFT JOIN dim_table dim
            ON stg.id = dim.id
            WHERE dim.id IS NULL;
```

And it works fine. So the table exists, and then could not be an error related to an accidental table drop.

Any suggests?

Comment: This is likely because the table `stg_table` specified in query4 no longer exists when you are trying to run query 4 in your python script.